# how to change form via ajax in yii?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am a new user on yii like what My problem is with'd like to form vary depending on the selected system after you click on the picture. Normally ajax code looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".getpaysystem").click(function() {
            var paydata = $(this).attr("id");                   

 $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'funkcja.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: {paydata: paydata},
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function(data)
        {
            jQuery('#Count').html(data);
        }
    });
            })

        });
```

when I click on the picture who has class = "getpaysystem" is ajax retrieve the id of the picture and call up the functions now as the file components / payform.php

```
 public function formone($banerid,$description,$amount,$currency){
echo CHtml::beginForm(EgoPaySci::EGOPAY_PAYMENT_URL, 'post');
echo CHtml::hiddenField('hash',Yii::app()->egopay->createBill($banerid,$description,$amount,$currency));
echo CHtml::submitButton('pay',array(
    'name'=>'paybutton',
));
echo CHtml::endForm();
    }
```

file view / pay.php

```
echo CHtml::link(CHtml::image('/images/3.png'), '#',array(
                'id'=>'formone',
                'class'=>'getpaysystem',
            ));
```

Normally when a file view will use the code

```
echo Yii::app()->payform->formone($banerid,$description,$amount,$currency);
...
or 
...
echo Yii::app()->payform->formtwo($banerid,$description,$amount,$currency);
```

I then displays correctly but I would like to get the effect of a few in the picture (chtml :: link ...) changed this function in view of formone on formtwo etc. With Thanks in advance for your answers